# how to "normalize" vectors values when using Spark CountVectorizer?

Tags: apache-spark, countvectorizer

`CountVectorizer` and `CountVectorizerModel` often creates a sparse feature vector that looks like this:

```
(10,[0,1,4,6,8],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

this basically says the total size of the vocabulary is 10, the current document has 5 unique elements, and in the feature vector, these 5 unique elements take position at 0, 1, 4, 6 and 8. Also, one of the elements show up twice, therefore the 2.0 value.

Now, I would like to "normalize" the above feature vector and make it look like this,

```
(10,[0,1,4,6,8],[0.3333,0.1667,0.1667,0.1667,0.1667])
```

i.e., each value is divided by 6, the total number of all elements together. For example, `0.3333 = 2.0/6`.

So is there a way to do this efficiently here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Normalizer`

> `class pyspark.ml.feature.Normalizer(*args, **kwargs)`
>
> Normalize a vector to have unit norm using the given p-norm.

with [1-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm)

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark.ml.feature import Normalizer

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (SparseVector(10,[0,1,4,6,8],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]), )
], ["features"])

Normalizer(inputCol="features", outputCol="features_norm", p=1).transform(df).show(1, False)
# +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |features                              |features_norm                                                                                                        |
# +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |(10,[0,1,4,6,8],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|(10,[0,1,4,6,8],[0.3333333333333333,0.16666666666666666,0.16666666666666666,0.16666666666666666,0.16666666666666666])|
# +--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```